# Verification of a Statement in Paper

Tags: group-theory

Let $G:=$ $2$-generated group with $G'=[G,G]$ abelian

$IA(G):=$ be the group of those automorphisms of $G$ which are identity on $G/[G,G]$

$D:= \{ f\in IA(G) : f\mbox{ is identity on [G,G]}\}$.

Then it is easy to see that $D$ is abelian.

**Question:** How to prove that $IA(G)/D$ is isomorphic to the group of units of quotient ring of the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G']$?

This was a statement in a paper, but I am not getting from where this group ring, group of units etc. entered in the discussion?

Link:
[see this](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-36/3/393.full.pdf), after equation (5), page 394.

Comment: Why don't you give a link (or bibliographic information) of that paper?